# When will User-defined Regions be available?

Tags: dxa-2.0, sites-9.1, sdl-cloud, dxa-dotnet

We need to implement "user-defined regions" in Sites 9.1 with DXA 2.2 to be able to deliver the front end design but see that the "DXA Container Framework" is deprecated for use with 8.5.

User-defined regions and standalone regions were announced by Rick Pannekoek in the SDL Tridion Sites 9 Technical Webinar – Regions and XPM Enhancement
Feb 23, 2018 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5xqP0lirms  (time:25:00)

When will user-defined regions be released?

Is DXA Container Framework Supported on our current dev platform?

Is DXA Container Framework supported on SDL Cloud?

Can we be sure that there is a simple upgrade path to user-defined regions from DXA Container Framework?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Defined Regions indeed seems to be a popular feature. See also SDL Ideas (ensure to leave a vote & comment there): https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/allow-editors-to-insert-regions-into-a-page

It has been high on the prioritized list of candidate features for quite a while, but unfortunately not high enough to make it into Sites 9.5.  Hopefully it makes it into 9.6 (no guarantee, though).

Indeed, the idea is that the DXA Container Framework can be used to fullfil this kind of functionality in XPM in the meantime.

The DXA Container Framework is a regular DXA Module, so I expect it to be supported on SDL Cloud, but it would be best to contact SDL Support for this.

Upgrade/migration to native Regions will never be really simple. There are PowerShell scripts available to migrate DXA implementations to native, pre-defined Regions.  When the User Defined Regions feature is implemented, similar scripts may be made available to migrate DXA Container Framework based implementations.

Comment: I will contact the SDL Cloud support team to check support and migration.

Answer (score 2):

The DXA Container Framework was more or less abandon when the region concept was introduced in Sites 9.0. If there are still are some interests I could look into reviving the framework again and adapt it the region concept + upgrade it to DXA 2.2. It could potentially serve as a gap filler until user defined regions are available in Tridion Sites.

Comment: Raised Issue on Github https://github.com/NiclasCedermalm/dxa-container-framework/issues/1#issue-648107333

Comment: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues/81